# Android NDK pretty printing

Tags: c++, android-ndk, pretty-print, std

I'm using Android NDK with Eclipse + CDT, running on OSX.

I would like to be able to debug the content of the STD library. I've seen several tutorials about using Python scripts to enable this "pretty printing". The problem is that all of them are using the default gdb, and not the one provided by the Android NDK, so all of them are failing for me.

How can I debug the STD library using Android NDK?

Comment: Interesting question, I have looked for such a possibility for a long time! Still no answer despite the bounty :-/.

Comment: I'm also looking for how to do pretty printing for Android NDK

Answer (score 4):

If you need to just debug, rather than make some already chosen tool work, I can share this code:

*dlog.h:*

```
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
#define DLOG(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
#define ELOG(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
```

I define both `DLOG` and `LOGD` to avoid having to remember the order ))

in *Android.mk:*

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ...
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog      # <=========== link with liblog.so
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Usage:

```
DLOG("this is a test %s 0x%x","whoa!",1234);
```

You see these messages in the same place where you see the `Log.d()` output, I prefer `adb logcat` or `adb logcat | grep something`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to have to write DLOG everyplace. I need to be able to check, for instance, a std::vector in a moment given, debuging with eclipse. Right now, it is just showing the memory directions.